# Beginner using php to create guest book that logs info to text file and displays data on separate page

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, text-files

I am a php beginner and I am working to create a guest book page that will accept a name and an email address from the user. Once they submit the form, the script writes this data to a text file. The user can then view all guest book entries. This is where I am having issues.

The guestbook page is creating the table data as desired, however the Name and Email portions are not calling the correct data. I am using the explode method and I think that is where I have confused myself and broken the program. I queried here and found nothing specific to this issue. I also dug through the documentation and I only confused myself more. Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong? I have included the source code for both files below:

sign-book.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
       Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
       <title>Post Message</title>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type"
            content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
       </head>
       <body>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $Name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
       $Email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);

       $Name = str_replace("~", "-", $Name);
       $Email = str_replace("~", "-", $Email);
       $MessageRecord = "$Name~$Email\n";
       $MessageFile = fopen("Guestbook/messages.txt", "ab");
       if ($MessageFile === FALSE)
            echo "There was an error saving your
                 entry.\n";
       else {
            fwrite($MessageFile, $MessageRecord);
            fclose($MessageFile);
            echo "Thank you for signing the Guest Book!\n";
       } 
}

?>

<h1>Please Sign the Guest Book</h1>
<hr />
<form action="sign-book.php" method="POST">
<span style="font-weight:bold">Name:</span>
     <input type="text" name="name" />
<span style="font-weight:bold">Email:</span>
     <input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit"
     value="Sign Guest Book" />
<input type="reset" name="reset"
     value="Reset Form" />
</form>
<hr />
<p>
<a href="guestbook.php">View Previous Entries</a>
</p>

       </body>
       </html>
```

guestbook.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
       Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
       <title>Message Board</title>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type"
            content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
       </head>
       <body>

<h1>Our Guestbook</h1>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
     if ((file_exists(
          "Guestbook/messages.txt")) &&
          (filesize(
          "Guestbook/messages.txt") != 0)) {
          $MessageArray = file(
               "Guestbook/messages.txt");
          switch ($_GET['action']) {
               case 'Delete Message':
                if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
                $Index = $_GET['message'];
                unset($MessageArray[$Index]);
                $MessageArray = array_values($MessageArray);
                }
                break;
               case 'Remove Duplicates':
                    $MessageArray = array_unique($MessageArray);
                    $MessageArray = array_values($MessageArray);
                    break;
               case 'Sort Ascending':
                    sort($MessageArray);
                    break;
                   case 'Sort Descending':
                    rsort($MessageArray);
                    break;
          } 

          if (count($MessageArray)>0) {
               $NewMessages = implode($MessageArray);
               $MessageStore = fopen("Guestbook/messages.txt", "wb");
               if ($MessageStore === false)
                    echo "There was an error
                         updating the message
                         file\n";
               else {
                    fwrite($MessageStore,
                         $NewMessages);
                    fclose($MessageStore);
               }
} else
         unlink("Guestbook/messages.txt");   
         }
  }  

if ((!file_exists("Guestbook/messages.txt"))
         || (filesize("Guestbook/messages.txt")
         == 0))
         echo "<p>There are no entries
              logged.</p>\n";
    else {
         $MessageArray = file("Guestbook/messages.txt");
         echo "<table
              style=\"background-color:lightgray\"
              border=\"1\" width=\"100%\">\n";

         $count = count($MessageArray);

         for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
            $CurrMsg = explode("~", $MessageArray[$i]);
            $KeyArray[] = $CurrMsg[0];
            $ValueArray[] = $CurrMsg[1];
            $KeyMessageArray = array_combine($KeyArray, $ValueArray);
         }

         $Index = 1;

         foreach($KeyMessageArray as $Message) { 
            $CurrMsg = explode("~", $Message); 
            echo "<tr>\n";
                echo "<td width=\"5%\"
                     style=\"text-align:center\"><span 
                     style=\"font-weight:bold\">" . 
                     $Index . "</span></td>\n";
          echo "<td width=\"85%\"><span
               style=\"font-weight:bold\">
               Name:</span> " .
               htmlentities($KeyArray[1]) . "<br />";
          echo "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">
               Email:</span> " . htmlentities($CurrMsg[0]) .
               "<br />";
                echo "<td width=\"10%\" 
                     style=\"text-align:center\">" . 
                     "<a href='guestbook.php?" . 
                     "action=Delete%20Message&" . 
                     "message=" . ($Index - 1) . 
                     "'>Delete This Entry</a>" . 
                     "</td>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n"; 
            ++$Index; 
            next($KeyMessageArray);
        }
         echo "</table>\n";
    }


?>
<p>
<a href="sign-book.php">
Log Another Entry</a><br />
<a href="guestbook.php?action=Sort%20Ascending">
Sort Subjects A-Z</a><br />
<a href="guestbook.php?action=Sort%20Descending">
Sort Subjects Z-A</a><br />
<a href="guestbook.php?action=Remove%20Duplicates">
Remove Duplicate Messages</a><br />
</p>   

       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already exploded `$MessageArray[$i]` by `~` here:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $CurrMsg = explode("~", $MessageArray[$i]);
    $KeyArray[] = $CurrMsg[0];
    $ValueArray[] = $CurrMsg[1];
    $KeyMessageArray = array_combine($KeyArray, $ValueArray);
}
```

So, now you have all names in `$KeyArray` and all emails in `$ValueArray`.
(By the way - if your names will be repeated, example `Paul, Paul, John` - oops)
Nevertheless, next you do:

```
foreach($KeyMessageArray as $Message) { 
    $CurrMsg = explode("~", $Message);
```

But why do you do this as `$Message` is an email already and definitely has NO `~` in it!

You should use `foreach` this way:

```
foreach($KeyMessageArray as $name => $email) { 
     // do stuff
}
```

**Update** about names:

so, as I said, when your names will repeat, your code will not work as expected. To avoid it - don't use name as a key, just use name and email as values for an array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $CurrMsg = explode("~", $MessageArray[$i]);
    // add both values to array:
    $KeyMessageArray[] = array(
        'name' => $CurrMsg[0],
        'email' => $CurrMsg[1],
    );
}

// next - iterate:
foreach($KeyMessageArray as $data) { 
    echo 'name is ' . $data['name'] . ', email is ' . $data['email'];
    // do stuff
}
```

And even further - you can do all stuff in **one** loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $CurrMsg = explode("~", $MessageArray[$i]);
    echo 'name is ' . $CurrMsg[0] . ', email is ' . $CurrMsg[1];
    // show some table stuff
}
```

Comment: u_mulder, this makes sense now, I updated my foreach loop and balance has been restored to my universe. You mentioned how names will be repeated due to the way I have this currently written. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is it possible to block users from signing the guestbook if they already have previously signed? Basically, can this script not allow for duplicates?

Comment: Get all names from your current file and check if name of a person exists there, for example with `in_array` function.

Comment: that makes sense. I hope I start to see when each function makes and where soon.